# Locale gives wrong output

Tags: localization, language

Got the following issue:
Building a site in 3 languages, Dutch, French & English

All working fine, except the siteurl for building the href link that's going wrong.
EN & NL ok, FR won't output.
If I call craft.locale, it says nl_be instead of fr.

Any ideas? I must be missing something...

Comment: How does your site know what locale to output anyway? Did you define it somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Question can be deleted, just found my mistake...

Apparently I've forgot to create the 'fr' folder and the index.php etc..

Working like a charm now!

Post, can be deleted as it won't be helping others

Comment: I dunno... I think your answer might be helpful to someone seeing similar behavior.

Comment: It certainly would've helped me then :)